# Run my own class with gulp in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, jasmine

I'm new with javascript and i would like to be able to test my code and be able to do TDD.

I was able to set up jasmine and run the tests with the index.html... it is good. But i would like to run it in command line and be able maybe to put this into jenkins for evey build.

Do you know guys if it is possible to do it ?

I will show my example just to be more clear:

src/calculator.js

```
function Calculator() {

  this.add = function(a,b) {
    return a + b;
  };

  this.multiply = function(a,b) {
    return a * b;
  };

  this.divide = function(a, b) {
    return a / b;
  };

};
```

test/spec/test.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  describe('CalculatorSuite', function () {

    var calculator = new Calculator();

    describe('we will perform some operation', function () {
      it('operation add', function () {
        expect(calculator.add(5,5)).toBe(10);
      });
    });

    describe('we will perform some operation', function () {
      it('operation multiply', function () {
        expect(calculator.multiply(5,5)).toBe(25);
      });
    });

    describe('we will perform some operation', function () {
      it('operation divide', function () {
        expect(calculator.divide(5,5)).toBe(1);
      });
    });


  });
})();
```

I would like to have a task `gulp test` and just says if the given test works or not but not using the index.html.

In other words.. if you guys have a jquery plugin or just your javascript class with your code.. what is the best way to test it ??

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want, you need to use a test runner like Karma.

You will need nodejs, install nodejs 8 (long term support version).

Then, you can init a package.json file with `npm init -f` to use defaults.

Then install the needed dependencies: karma, jasmine-core, karma-jasmine, etc:

`npm install gulp jasmine jasmine-core karma karma-chrome-launcher karma-jasmine --save-dev`

Your `package.json` will look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "calculator.js",
  "scripts": {
    "karma": "karma start",
    "gulp": "gulp"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

Notice I added two sample script tasks that you can run with npm, but you don't need them, let's focus on gulp as that's why you are asking for.

So create a `gulpfile.js` and add the karma task:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
var karma = require('karma').Server;

gulp.task('karma', function (done) {
  new karma({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }, done).start();
});
```

You need a `karma.conf.js` file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'calculator.js',
      'test.js'
    ],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    port: 9876,
    singleRun: true
  })
};
```

Notice I am using the Chrome driver there. If you use a different browser, check the documentation for it.

Then run `gulp karma` if you have it global on your system, you will see an output like:

```
> stackoverflow@1.0.0 karma D:\dev\stackoverflow\jasmine
> karma start

27 11 2017 14:58:32.317:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
27 11 2017 14:58:32.321:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
27 11 2017 14:58:32.330:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
27 11 2017 14:58:33.045:INFO [Chrome 62.0.3202 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket Yst3dx48_MFL7
VudAAAA with id 50722983
Chrome 62.0.3202 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.009 secs / 0.003 secs)
```

or you can run `npm run karma` using one of the `scripts` I added in the `package.json` if you don't have `gulp` globally on your system.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer @Juan. What is the advantage of have a node module ? in other words, to be able to test a simple js it is necessary to change it to a node module ? if i want to add this calculator.js in my website (old school) is it going to affect those lines or do i need to use it with node or angular ? I would like to be able to find a mechanism to be able to test easy javascript, can be jquery or plain javascript. For example, if i develpo a simple solution for a wordpress plugin and i'm using a script or a class. What do you thing it is the best way to do it ?

Comment: @eballo in that case use Karma as your runner. See my updated answer that does exactly what you are asking for. No need to modify the files in that case.

Comment: now I like it more! Then i don't need to change my simple javascript file to node module. Thank you very much for your help Juan!